# DBCS not saving properly

Tags: php, utf-8

I have an edit.php file which will allow me to edit the contents of a web form. All the text is stored in .txt files. The problem comes when I try to enter characters in Japanese, or Korean etc.

I will input this: "たんじょびおめでとう"

and once I save it, it returns this: "%u305F%u3093%u3058%u3087%u3073%u304A%u3081%u3067%u3068%u3046"

Does any one have any ideas as to how to have the characters saved correctly. I find if I change the encoding on the .txt files to UTF-8 and input the characters using notepad rather then through edit.php it tends to save fine, though I'd rather not have to do this.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**
I wasn't sure what code to put, but I'm assuming it's to do with my way of saving. Here is my save.php file:

```
$content = $_POST['content'];  
if($content == ''){  
 echo "You cannot null this field, please reload the page.";  
} else {  
  echo $content;  
  $myFile = "text/".$_POST['id'].".txt";  
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Could not update");  
  fwrite($fh,$content);  
  fclose($fh);  
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to handle the data.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check which character encoding you're inputing with (probably ISO 8859-1 or CP 1252 on Windows).

In any case, transforming your returned string into the desired output encoding should be easy, as your string:

> %u305F%u3093%u3058%u3087%u3073%u304A%u3081%u3067%u3068%u3046

Are the 10 Unicode escape sequences (UTF-8) for the Japanese you have entered ("Happy Birthday"). When you input them directly into a text file, I'm assuming the application is setting the encoding correctly.

If it's for a web form, check what the encoding is set to in the request header, for example:

```
Content-Type    text/xml;charset=utf-8
```